# android: authorize.net api for creating account

Tags: android, authorize.net, user-accounts

I want to use authorize.net in my app for online payments. I want to know if there are any apis to create an account in authorize.net from my mobile app. I want the user to create the authorize.net account from my app. I couldnt fine any api for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is not an API for this. You have to register through their website and only after having a US merchant account.